# What effect do parenthesis do on a scope block?

Tags: c, scope, parentheses

I know that it is commonly used in macros:

```
#define MY_MACRO(x)  ({ int var = x; /* do stuff */; var; })
...
y = MY_MACRO(43);
```

But how exactly is it interpreted by the compiler? To my understanding, parentheses in C are used for:

1. Isolation (of conditions)
2. Group expressions (for precedence)
3. Function indication
4. Casting

I don't understand how any of the above is applied here on the scope block but apparently it does the "magic":

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int a;

    // a = {3};  // --> compilation error "expected expression before '{' token"
    // a = {3;}; // --> Same error
    a = ({3;});  // --> all is good!
    a = ({0; 1; 2; 3;});  // --> warnings for unused values but still, all is good!

    printf("a=%d\n", a); // prints a=3

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It’s a GCC extension.  IIRC, it is a ‘statement expression’.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, Really? so all these macros are not portable?

Comment: Yup; they’re not portable to compilers that do not support that extension.